# Comparing two dropdownlist values and change items in third dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

It will be great , if you assist me.

I have three dropdownlists.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" class="form-control input-sm" runat="server" Width="147px">
  <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>48</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" class="form-control input-sm" runat="server" Width="147px">
  <asp:ListItem>0.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>1.0</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>1.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>2.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>3.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>4.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>8.5</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>48</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" class="form-control input-sm" runat="server" Width="147px">
  <asp:ListItem>MET</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Threatened</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Breached</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now my question is :

If dropdownlist 1 value > dropdownlist2 value then , I should only see Met item in dropdownlist3 (remaining two items should hide.)

And again ,

If dropdownlist 1 value < dropdownlist2 value then , I should only see Breached item in dropdownlist3 (remaining two items should hide.)

Can you help with this code???

Comment: so what you are asking....its logical?

Comment: Google "SelectedIndexChanged Event for Drop down"

Comment: I think you want a simple jQuery function to hide/show using hide() dependent on the values of the dropdown lists.

Comment: I have trying this code :

 Dim drp1 As Integer = DropDownList11.SelectedItem.Value
        Dim drp2 As Integer = DropDownList12.SelectedItem.Value

        If (drp1 > drp2) Then

            Label1.Text = "Met"

        End If

Answer (score 0):

Add the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to `DropDownList1` and `DropDownList2` and set `AutoPostBack` to `true`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the values from the dropdownlists
    decimal selectedValue1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    decimal selectedValue2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

    //clear all listitems from dropdownlist3
    DropDownList3.Items.Clear();

    //add the listitems based on the selected values
    if (selectedValue1 > selectedValue2)
    {
        DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("MET", "MET", true));
    }
    else if (selectedValue1 < selectedValue2)
    {
        DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Breached", "Breached", true));
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Threatened", "Threatened", true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in your front end

Add `AutoPostBack="True"` in both `DropDownList1` & `DropDownList2`

Now in Back end on you Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
            DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            if (a > b)
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, "MET");
            }
            else if (a < b)
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, "Breached");
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, "MET");
                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(1, "Breached");
                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(2, "Threatened");
            }
        }
    }
```